# How to prevent iframe from loading when injected into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, frame, code-injection

How to prevent iframe from loading when injected into the DOM?

For example, this code creates an iframe with a src that begins a download.

```
f = B.Node.create('<iframe class="offscreen" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="' + d + '" src="' + Z + Y + '">');
F("body").appendChild(f);
```

Without any libraries, what are ways to prevent the iframe from loading or to stop the download?

Preventing the iframe injection is also acceptable.

Is it a good idea to modify the behavior of "appendChild()"?

I'm using Opera 11.50 Build 1074.

Comment: Why are you injecting an IFrame if you don't want it to have content?

Comment: @GolezTrol, I'm not injecting the iframe. Someone else is. I have no control over Yahoo! Mail's JavaScript on Yahoo!'s server. Yahoo! Mail is injecting the iframe.

Comment: Do you have control over the loading of that script in your document, or is third-party content loading the script?

Comment: @Jacob, I can have control over the script on the client side. I have made a User JS that works. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/1126767/

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Enhance Yahoo! Mail
// @author XP1 (https://github.com/XP1/)
// @namespace https://gist.github.com/1126767/
// @version 1.0
// @description In Yahoo! Mail, opens the download iframe in a new window so that the attachment can be opened if the file type is associated with the Opera browser.
// @include http*://mail.yahoo.*/*
// @include http*://*.mail.yahoo.*/*
// @include http*://mail.yimg.*/*
// @include http*://*.mail.yimg.*/*
// @include http*://yahooapis.*/*
// @include http*://*.yahooapis.*/*
// ==/UserScript==

/*jslint browser: true, vars: true, white: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4 */
(function (topWindow)
{
    "use strict";

    if (window.self === topWindow)
    {
        var disableDownloadIframe = function ()
        {
            topWindow.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (event)
            {
                var sourceElement = event.srcElement;
                if (sourceElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "iframe" && sourceElement.hasAttribute("id") && sourceElement.getAttribute("id").indexOf("#dlFrame") !== -1)
                {
                    var downloadLink = sourceElement.getAttribute("src");
                    sourceElement.parentNode.removeChild(sourceElement);

                    window.open(downloadLink);
                }
            }, false);
        };

        disableDownloadIframe.call(this);
    }
}(window.top));
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overwrite functions like `appendChild`, in all (if any) browsers.  The only way to prevent iframes from being injected is to not include any JavaScript libraries that do arbitrary DOM injection.

If it's your own code you want to prevent from inserting iframes, simple add some HTML "sanitizing" functionality.

Answer (score 1):

append empty iframe

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe').setAttribute('id', 'myiFrame'));
```

when you want to load the content:

```
document.getElementById('myiFrame').setAttribute('src', 'http://blah.com/blah.htm');
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing and when I create it without `src` the iframe loads with an empty <head> and an empty <body>. Maybe it used to work in the past...