# Why script elements created through DOMParser do not execute?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-script-loading

I'm loading HTML in Ajax, parsing it with `DOMParser` and put all the `childNodes` of the document body into a document fragment.

When I add the fragment into the current document's body, `<script>` tags aren't executed.

I fiddled around and figured out that if I replace them with new dynamically created script tags, they get correctly executed.

**I would like to know WHY?**

E.g.

```
var html = "Some html with a script <script>alert('test');</script>";

var frag = parsePartialHtml(html);


fixScriptsSoTheyAreExecuted(frag);


document.body.appendChild(frag);


function fixScriptsSoTheyAreExecuted(el) {
  var scripts = el.querySelectorAll('script'),
      script, fixedScript, i, len;

  for (i = 0, len = scripts.length; i < len; i++) {
    script = scripts[i];

    fixedScript = document.createElement('script');
    fixedScript.type = script.type;
    if (script.innerHTML) fixedScript.innerHTML = script.innerHTML;
    else fixedScript.src = script.src;
    fixedScript.async = false;

    script.parentNode.replaceChild(fixedScript, script);
  }
}


function parsePartialHtml(html) {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html'),
      frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
      childNodes = doc.body.childNodes;

  while (childNodes.length) frag.appendChild(childNodes[0]);

  return frag;
}
```

Without calling `fixScriptsSoTheyAreExecuted`, nothing will execute.

Another point that I find hard to follow is that if I try to simply clone the existing script nodes to create new ones using `cloneNode`, it doesn't work, which kinds of suggest that the script tags that were initially created by the `DOMParser` carries state that prevent them from being executed.

Comment: @Nit, That's not true at all. Dynamically added scripts are definitely executed. I'm asking why scripts dynamically created through the `DOMParser` object do not execute like the ones created using `document.createElement`.

Comment: Its also worth noting that this code also only works when you make the new `fragment` and move the nodes over. If you just try and append the parsed nodes directly to the main document, with or without the `fix` method, scripts wont execute

Comment: I find another way to execute the scripts -- create an iframe, set the `src`, then read `frame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML` -- but it only works in limited cases (CORS). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340324/loading-an-iframe-without-injecting-it-into-the-dom

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is explained in the [DOM Parsing and Serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#widl-DOMParser-parseFromString-Document-DOMString-str-SupportedType-type) spec:

> **`parseFromString`**
>
> The `parseFromString(str, type)` method must run these steps,
>   depending on type:
>
> - `"text/html"`
>
>   Parse `str` with an [`HTML parser`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#html-parser), and return the newly created [document](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-document).
>
>   The [scripting flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#scripting-flag) must be set to "disabled".
>
>   **Note**
>     [`script`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#script) elements get marked unexecutable and the contents of
>     [`noscript`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-noscript-element) get parsed as markup.

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought to look at the spec ;)