# How to ask for a specific element using Xmlhttprequest parameters

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

The element I am looking for:

```html
<h1 id="itemSummaryPrice" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">42 - 47</h1>
```

I wanna make a chrome extension that uses XMLHttpRequest GET METHOD for checking a value on another Website, i know i can give the URL, parameters for scaling down the response. So my question is how do I make an URL that gives me only the element in the response that I am looking for ? if its even possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Well, it's not possible using just a URL, you could ofc use a parser and return the item after you loaded it in

Comment: would that mean that i have to parse the hole response, using regex or something else ?

Comment: Not RegEx, _[You can't parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6634591)_, but a DOMParser would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't request only one part (node) of a document. You'll have to request the whole thing, parse it then select from it what you want:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", yourUrl);

request.onload = function() {
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(request.responseText, "text/html");
    var el = doc.getElementById("itemSummaryPrice"); // the element you want
}

request.send(null);
```

Or you can set the `responseType` to `"document"` and let the `XMLHttpRequest` do the parsing internally, then use `responseXML`:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", yourUrl);
request.responseType = "document";

request.onload = function() {
    var doc = request.responseXML;
    var el = doc.getElementById("itemSummaryPrice"); // the element you want
}

request.send(null);
```

Comment: The last problem I am having is, I can't get the text, the "42 - 47" of my snippet. Do you have an idea how or what I should look for when asking for var el ? I tried .innerText but no chances.

Comment: no, your code is correct but the var el gives this element back:
<h1 id="itemSummaryPrice"></h1> 
But I needed the value in the innerText, but it seems gone

Comment: @Tomale Try `el.textContent`.

Comment: nop, its also not working it seems as if the element that i get from the  getElment is just taking the <h1 id="itemSummaryPrice"></h1> and ignoring the other values in the html element ...

Comment: @Tomale I think the server is sending you that element without any content. Or, worse, the content of the element is populated later by a script (which won't be executed if you'are using a parser). Read more about it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28112807/6647153).