# Script parsed using DOMParser does not execute

Tags: javascript, dom

When I create a script element using `document.createElement` and append it to `document.head`, the JavaScript executes successfully:

```js
var el = document.createElement('script');
el.text = "console.log('Hello World!')";
document.head.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', el);
// console output: "Hello World!"
```

But if I use a DOMParser to parse an html string and then append its `firstElementChild` to `document.head`, the JavaScript does not execute:

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlString = "<script>console.log('Bye World!')<\/script>";
var domEl = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/xml").firstElementChild;
document.head.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', domEl);
// No console output
```

A `<script>` tag is added to `document.head` in both the cases. Why does the JavaScript not execute in the second case?

Comment: See also: [javascript - Why script elements created through DOMParser do not execute? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112807/why-script-elements-created-through-domparser-do-not-execute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `DOMParser` marks the `script` element so that it won't be run, since the DOMParser parses `text/xml` (and others) with scripting disabled ([spec](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#the-domparser-interface)). Whether the script should be run is a piece of state information associated with the `script` element, which is why this doesn't run the script twice:

```js
var el = document.createElement('script');
el.text = "console.log('Hello World!')";
document.head.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', el);
document.head.removeChild(el);
document.head.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: Create another script tag with the content of `domEl` could solve the problem.

Comment: @3142maple - Indeed. I sort of assumed given the sophistication of the question, that the OP would know what to do... :-)