# Execute code from inline script that is fetched from another source

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app and am fetching index.html from one server location and want to run its scripts from another server location:

```
 const entries = await axios.get(`http://localhost:xxx`);
 let domParser = new DOMParser();
 let tempDOM = domParser.parseFromString(entries.data, 'text/html');
 const scriptLoads = tempDOM.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(script => 
    if (!script.src) {
        const inlineScript = document.createTextNode(eval(script.text));
        scriptElement.appendChild(inlineScript);
        document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
      } 
 )
```

The above code grabs the inline  tags included inside **index.html**. It would do the job (`executing the inline script`) if `eval` should not be prevented from running. To be honest, am not sure what exactly is blocking eval. However, my question is how we can change the above code and not using eval. Is there any orthodox way? I have tried a lot of things, however nothing works...

For example the following works fine:

```
document.createTextNode("alert('Hello World!');");
```

but not this one:

```
document.createTextNode(script.text);
```

Comment: Related question: [javascript - Why script elements created through DOMParser do not execute? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112807/why-script-elements-created-through-domparser-do-not-execute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security concerns aside, you can create a script element in your webpage and insert the inline script contents into it.

```
const entries = await axios.get(`http://localhost:xxx`);
let domParser = new DOMParser();
let tempDOM = domParser.parseFromString(entries.data, 'text/html');
tempDOM.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(script => 
    if (!script.src) {
        const inlineScript = document.createElement('script');
        inlineScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        inlineScript.innerHTML = script.innerHTML;
        document.body.appendChild(inlineScript);
    } 
);
```

You should only do this if you trust the other server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have tried @FThomson solution, which seems to be the right way, and for some reason it does not fit your specific use case there is a window.location trick you may consider:

```
window.location = 'javascript:alert("hello")'
```